# Drupal node form conditionally remove required status from fields

Tags: drupal-7, field, nodes, required

I am trying to programmatically remove the required status from some node/*/edit fields. The required status is set by default and should only be removed based on the selected value in a taxonomy field:

Using the following code:

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if( $form_id == 'job_node_form' ){
        $form['#after_build'] = array('test');
    }
}

function test(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['title']['#required'] = FALSE; // works
    $form['jobs_schools_data']['field_job_type']['#required'] = FALSE; // does NOT work
    return $form;
}
```

I find I can successfully remove the required status from the title field but the same does not work for the fields I added like **field_job_type** in the code example above.

Why doesn't this work, and how I might correct it?

Comment: Are you sure access to the right element , if you dump `$form` ? maybe try to add `$form_state['rebuild'] = true;` to `test` function

Comment: Other wise , delete required by default and make your hook_validate on node to apply conditons

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, in the actual form I did not set the required status on two fields, only one is supposed to show if certain criteria was met. I then created a custom function to check if a field was populated and based on that I then set the error message from there.

```
function events_registration_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
     $selected_time = $form_state['values']['time_selected'];
if ($form_state['values']['time_selected'] == '') {
  form_set_error('time_selected', t('Please choose an event time.'));
```

Comment: Thanks very much Johanna but I an not trying to set an error alert. Rather, I am trying to disable required error alerts on individual fields based on some condition. Thanks for responding all the same